# Как сделать таймер для выпадающего окна.

Tags: таймер, всплывающее-окно, javascript

**Здравствуйте!**

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть **впадающее окно оно выпадает при нажатии на ссылку**. Как сделать так чтобы к событию по клику, привязать параллельно событие по которому это **окно будет выпадать через 10 секунд после загрузки страницы**. Т.е. если на ссылку не нажал, оно всё равно выпадет через 10 сек.

**Пример** при нажатии **[Здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les587/demo/demo.html)**! **Вот код скрипта выпадающего окна**:**

$(document).ready(function(){

```
/* Конвертируем тэг div #box в bounceBox: */
$('#box').bounceBox();

/* При поступлении события нажатия кнопки мыши на переключаем выпадающее окно: */
$('a.button').click(function(e){

    $('#box').bounceBoxToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});

/* Если в области выпадающего окна была нажата кнопка мыши, то открываем окно: */
$('#box').click(function(){
    $('#box').bounceBoxHide();
});
```

});

***Заранее благодарен!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто таймаут, и проще всего вызвать само событие послав клик объекту:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#main .button').click();
},10000)
```

там же туториал, в туториале есть объявленные методы show/hide можно их по таймауту вызвать...

Comment: Спасибо большое, просто я не силён javascript, поэтому такие вопросы. Если, по рекомендуете какой-нибудь урок для чайников буду признателен!

Comment: @cheh вот неплохой ресурс по JavaScript: http://javascript.ru/